# Is there a way to distinguish between "Ctrl+Backspace" and "Ctrl+h" in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, keystroke

I read that, in most Linux terminals, "ctrl+backspace" key produces `^H`. However, "ctrl+h" key natively produces `^H`. Then what if I would like to bind "ctrl+h" to a function and "ctrl+backspace" to another function? Is it possible? Or should I just embrace this?

> For information, I saw common questions in the internet asking "ctrl+backspace" just working as "backspace", which results from some terminals not being able to distinguish between them (both `^?`). To make sure, my question is different. In my terminal "ctrl+backspace" == `^H` and "backspace" == `^?`, which seems normal.

- I'm using `Kitty` for terminal on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: What kind of "linux terminal"? The virtual terminal or some terminal emulator? If the latter, which one?

Comment: Good point! I edited.

Comment: If your terminal differentiates and your software supports it, you bind them to whatever you want. Just be aware that you probably won't be able to use them the same way from a different terminal (including in screen/tmux)